# WPF - How to detect if transform was performed

Tags: c#, wpf, win-universal-app

I am creating animation for "menu panel". This animation should be performed after button tap, but this is the problem. I have one button which should execute two animations. Is any way, how to detect, if transform was performed already and decide which one have to be executed after click?

Something like:

```
if (DataPanel.Transformed)    //what atribute to check?
        {
            ((Storyboard)Resources["dataPanelHideSB"]).Begin();
        }
        else
        {
            ((Storyboard)Resources["dataPanelShowSB"]).Begin();
        }
```

Before animation implementation I used margin check to decide, if panel is hidden or not, but within TranslateTransform is influenced realWidth/realHeight(?), which I am not able to compare.

Former version:

```
if (DataPanel.Margin.Top != 0) 
        {
            DataPanel.Margin = new Thickness(0, ((Window.Current.Bounds.Height / 6) * 4), 0, -((Window.Current.Bounds.Height / 6) * 4));
        }
        else
        {
            DataPanel.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out just after posting this question. Solution is quite simple:

```
if(((Storyboard)Resources["dataPanelShowSB"]).GetCurrentState() == ClockState.Filling )
    {
        ((Storyboard)Resources["dataPanelHideSB"]).Begin();
        ((Storyboard)Resources["dataPanelShowSB"]).Stop();
    }
    else
    {
        ((Storyboard)Resources["dataPanelShowSB"]).Begin();
    }
```